# Django apps sharing a model

Tags: django, django-apps

I Django can 2 apps share 1 model, or 2 apps must define the same model inside. so app1 and app1 can have have same products model inside them for example?

Comment: Can Django apps have no models at all?

Comment: Absolutely. If you have no data to store or display in a database, such as if you just wanted to serve static content like images and css, you could easily do this with no models.

If you have a homepage and apps, you could host them together with django, the homepage "app" possibly having no models.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `app1` and `app2` can share the same model. You need to import it wherever you want to use it.

Lets say your project structure is like below having 2 apps `app1` and `app2`.

```
my_project/
    manage.py
    my_project/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py  
    app1/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    app2/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
```

Then to use the models defined in `app1/models.py` in `app2`, you just need to do:

```
from app1.models import MyModel # import the model
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import the model from the app that defines it to the app that is using it.